# R: why when merging data - got a result that is larger than both of the data

Tags: r, merge

I have two data sets like the following:

dataA:

```
newPCODE1   INT
 T306     986566   
 U078     94333    
 T324     97170   
 R354     97489   
 T538     987411    
 R141     94334
 ...
```

dataB:

```
 newPCODE1 PRICE
 A001  2535
 A002  1200
 A003  1560
 A004  2575
 A005  5575
 A006  1140
 ....
```

dataA has about 400,000 rows and dataB has about 40,000 rows, but when i did merge using the following function, I got a data that is about 500,000. I am wondering why this is happening, and both data has only one column that shares name - newPCODE1. I tried to google around but did not find much information. Would appreciate any insights!

```
combo_new = merge(dataA,dataB, by = "newPCODE1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `newPCODE1` match will add a row to your merged data frame, including repeats of a code. For example, if `T306` appears twice in `dataA` and three times in `dataB`, you'll get six rows in your merged data frame from that value of `newPCODE1` (because the first `T306` in `dataA` matches three rows in `dataB` and the second `T306` in `dataA` matches those same three rows in `dataB`).

To calculate the number of rows in the merged data frame:

First, only `newPCODE1` values that are in both data frames will be returned from the `merge` (in the form used in your question). In other words, we need the intersection of `newPCODE1` from the two data frames:

```
common.codes = intersect(dataA$newPCODE1,dataB$newPCODE1)
```

The number of rows returned for each value of `newPCODE1` will be the product of the number of rows with that value of `newPCODE1` in each of the two data frames. The total number of rows in the merged data frame is the sum of these products:

```
sum(table(dataA$newPCODE1[dataA$newPCODE1 %in% common.codes]) * 
      table(dataB$newPCODE1[dataB$newPCODE1 %in% common.codes]))
```

In the example below, note that the merged data frame has 25 rows, even though the original two data frames have only a total of 20. If all 10 rows had the same `newPCODE1` value in both data frames, the merged data frame would have had 100 rows. (If, say, `T306` appeared in all 400,000 rows of `dataA` and all 40,000 rows of `dataB`, your merged data frame would have 400,000*40,000 = 16 billion rows!)

```
dataA = data.frame(newPCODE1=c(1,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6), value1=letters[1:10])
dataB = data.frame(newPCODE1=c(3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,10), value2=LETTERS[1:10])
merge(dataA,dataB, by="newPCODE1")
```

> ```
>    newPCODE1 value1 value2
> 1          3      b      A
> 2          4      c      B
> 3          4      d      B
> 4          5      e      C
> 5          5      e      D
> 6          5      e      E
> 7          5      f      C
> 8          5      f      D
> 9          5      f      E
> 10         6      g      G
> 11         6      g      H
> 12         6      g      I
> 13         6      g      F
> 14         6      h      G
> 15         6      h      H
> 16         6      h      I
> 17         6      h      F
> 18         6      i      G
> 19         6      i      H
> 20         6      i      I
> 21         6      i      F
> 22         6      j      G
> 23         6      j      H
> 24         6      j      I
> 25         6      j      F
> ```

```
common.codes = intersect(dataA$newPCODE1,dataB$newPCODE1)

sum(table(dataA$newPCODE1[dataA$newPCODE1 %in% common.codes]) * 
      table(dataB$newPCODE1[dataB$newPCODE1 %in% common.codes]))
```

> ```
> [1] 25
> ```

If you want to keep rows from one or both data frames even when there is no matching row in the other data frame, you can do this:

```
merge(dataA,dataB, by="newPCODE1", all.x=TRUE)   # Keep all rows from first data frame
merge(dataA,dataB, by="newPCODE1", all.y=TRUE)   # Keep all rows from second data frame
merge(dataA,dataB, by="newPCODE1", all=TRUE)     # Keep all rows from both data frames
```

Comment: I checked in dataB, every PCODE1 is unique and there could be multiple or non matching PCODE1 in dataA. What I am trying to is to extract the those intersect rows and add other features from dataB to the selected dataA, so I am guessing it is still INNER JOINER but I when I tried combo_new <- merge(dataA, dataB, by.x="newPCODE1", by.y="newPCODE1") or my original code, it still returns a data of about 500,000 rows that is larger than both dataA and dataB/

Comment: I figured it out. I accidentally used another product ID that is not unique in dataB. Thanks a lot for the illustration.

Answer (score 2):

you should do the merge as follows.

`combo_new <- merge(dataA, dataB, by.x="newPCODE1", by.y="newPCODE1")`

But I think that your main problem is uniqueness, is there an exact 1-1 mapping of `newPCODE1`? If there is more than one it could be trying to match all the matches. for example (A,A,B,C) x (A,B,C) would have A1 to A1 and A1 to A2 in addition to B1 B1 and C1 C1. Hence the additional matches.